# Graphical Data Mapping for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, datamapper, dozer

I´m looking for an open source graphical data mapper for Java/Eclipse that can map between POJOs.

Something similar to [Mapforce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce/eclipse-integration.html), [Mule Studio's data mapper](http://www.mulesoft.com/webinars/graphical-data-mapping-mule) component or Dozer (but visual).

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try Oakland Software's [Oakland Data Transformer](http://oaklandsoftware.com/data-transformer). It works with Camel or Mule and also has an API that works directly with Java.

The support for Java classes is very complete.

(Dislaimer, I run Oakland Software)

Comment: Thanks. Looks great but it's not OSS.